# AWS S3 'CloudSearch'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Gone through amazon SDK/documentation and there isn't a lot around programtically querying/searching for documents on S3 bucket.
Sure, can get document by  id/name but i want to have ability to search by other meta tags such as author.

Would appreciate some guidance and a specific example of a query being executed and not a local iteration once all documents or items have been pulled locally.

Answer (score 1):

> […] there isn't a lot around programtically querying/searching for documents on S3 bucket.

Right. S3 is flat file storage, and doesn't provide a query interface.

> […] i want to have ability to search by other meta tags such as author.

This will need to be solved by your application logic. This is not built-in to S3.

For example, you can store the metadata about an S3 document/file in DynamoDB. You query DynamoDB for the metadata, which includes a pointer to the file in S3.

Unfortunately, if you already have a bunch of files in S3, you'll need to find a way to build that initial index of your data.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping to use 'CloudSearch' directly instead of a work around by defining SDF and use those to search on.

Answer (score -1):

Amazon just released new features for cloud search
http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/03/24/amazon-cloudsearch-introduces-powerful-new-search-and-admin-features/.